# How to address dependent observations in a multinomial logistic regression model

Tags: r, regression, glmm, multinomial-logit

I'm studying the influence of fund size and board diversity on the voting behavior of pension funds (in terms of voting on shareholder resolutions at companies they invest in). My dependent variable, 'voting behavior', is categorical (for, against, abstained, divest, no investment). My independent variables are age diversity and gender diversity (whereby age range and percentage of women are used).

My supervisor agrees with me that I should use a multinomial logistic regression model, but she says my observations are not independent of each other because I have data on 38 pension funds across multiple years. Furthermore, the pension funds have voted on 8 different companies.

I think a mixed effects multinomial regression model would be suitable but I am really confused about which package and how I should do it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The `mgcv` package of `R` may be a good start. In this package, you can find the function `gam` which is capable of fitting multinomial regression models with random effects.

I'm not super familiar with this particular use of the `gam` function but I doubt it can handle random effects with complicated structures, as does `lme` for Gaussian responses for instance.

Here is a simple example to start from.

```
library(mgcv)

set.seed(6)
## simulate some data from a three class model
n <- 1000
f1 <- function(x) sin(3*pi*x)*exp(-x)
f2 <- function(x) x^3
f3 <- function(x) .5*exp(-x^2)-.2
f4 <- function(x) 1
x1 <- runif(n);x2 <- runif(n)
eta1 <- 2*(f1(x1) + f2(x2))-.5
eta2 <- 2*(f3(x1) + f4(x2))-1
p <- exp(cbind(0,eta1,eta2))
p <- p/rowSums(p) ## prob. of each category 
cp <- t(apply(p,1,cumsum)) ## cumulative prob.
## simulate multinomial response with these probabilities
## see also ?rmultinom
y <- apply(cp,1,function(x) min(which(x>runif(1))))-1
## plot simulated data...
plot(x1,x2,col=y+3)
id =  rep(1:10, 100)

## now fit the model...
b <- gam(list(y~x1+x2+ s(as.factor(id), bs="re"),
              ~ x1+x2+s(as.factor(id), bs="re")),
         family=multinom(K=2))
summary(b)
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the following code:
model <- gam(list(Vote ~ Gender + Age + s(Pension_Fund, bs = "re") + s(Company, bs = "re"),
                   ~ Gender + Age + s(Pension_Fund, bs = "re") + s(Company, bs = "re"),
                   ~ Gender + Age + s(Pension_Fund, bs = "re") + s(Company, bs = "re"),
                   ~ Gender + Age + s(Pension_Fund, bs = "re") + s(Company, bs = "re")),
              family = multinom(K = 4), data = data)
However, I get the following error:
Error in Math.factor(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  : 
  ‘round’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: Which is weird since I do not have any missing or invalid values (I checked) + the variables Vote, Pension_Fund and Company are factors (rightfully so). Do you know what may be causing this error?